# Meaning of a simple preg_replace('!\s+!') pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Sorry for the very basic question, but there's no easy way to search for a string like that. I have searched in PHP Manual (Pattern Syntax & preg_replace) but I haven't found any answers.

This code is inside a function that receives the $filter parameter.
What does that preg_replace serves for?

$filter = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $filter);

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3933332

Comment: It replaces all whitespace chunks with a single space.

Comment: Maybe exclamation point can sound strange: it is only a delimiter, you can change it with `/` or any other char not in pattern. `!\s+!` is the same as `/\s+/`